# Bootstrap modal-backdrop height when using .load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `.load` to load content with ajax into bootstrap modal body. However, the height of the modal-backdrop isn't from top to bottom as i guess it is firing the modal before the actual images have loaded into the modal. [According to bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) we should be using `.load` and not the `remote` functionality

CSS

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: absolute; - even tried with fixed
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

jQuery I tried to try firing the modal once the content has been loaded

```
$(this).parent().find(".modal-body").load(cont,function(data){
   thisModal.modal();
});
```

However, the callback is still firing before the images have loaded. The only real solution I have got is using css and doing:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    min-height: 2000px;
}
```

Is it there any better way?

Comment: Possibly you could first load the content in the modal and then make the modal visible. I am not sure if the .ajaxStop method will fire when you are using .load. If it does though you can use it to show the modal when the load is completed.

Comment: is it not what I have tried to do using the callback in my .load? And it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

you can get image height and width before model show and you can set them into your css style

http://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/eWzWg/68/

```
    $(this).parent().find(".modal-body").load(cont,function(data){

    $("#im").one('load',function(){ //add img id "im"
    orgWidth = this.width;
    orgHeight = this.height;
    alert(orgHeight);
  $('.modal-backdrop').css('min-height', orgHeight);  
  });
     thisModal.modal();
    });
```

Comment: what if you have a set of images with different heights?

Comment: updated is this marching with your problem ? you can add id for img element and use that